# Compare two text files and if the second file has a row which contains both the columns of first file delete that row

Tags: linux, awk, sed, text-processing

I have two files as shown below. file1 has two columns and file2 has varying number of columns depending on the row. I want to compare both files and if $1 and $2 both of file1 is in a row of file2, I want to delete that row. Also file2 is comma separated. How can this be done using awk? or any other text processing tools?

**file1**

```
5052 5051  
4952 4951
```

**file2**

```
         2001,       5052,       7001,       5051,       1000  
         2002,       5052,       7001,       1500,       2500  
         2003,       5051,       3500,       4500,       4952  
         2004,       4952,       4999,       4500,       4951
```

**Expected output:**

```
         2002,       5052,       7001,       1500,       2500  
         2003,       5051,       3500,       4500,       4952
```

I have tried below awk code but did not run.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$1;A[$2]=$2; next} {if ($0=A[$1] && $0=A[$2]){next} else {print $0}' file1 file2 >> test.inp
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in your question(keep it up), could you please also post samples of expected output for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: `if ($0=A[$1] && $0=A[$2])`... - are you sure you want to do assignment (`=`) in condition rather than comparison (`==`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes the pairs in file1 never have the same value in both fields:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    pairs1[NR] = $1
    pairs2[NR] = $2
    next
}
{
    orig = $0
    gsub(/[[:space:],]+/," ")
    delete vals
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        vals[$i]
    }
    for (nr in pairs1) {
        if ( (pairs1[nr] in vals) && (pairs2[nr] in vals) ) {
            next
        }
    }
    print orig
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
         2002,       5052,       7001,       1500,       2500
         2003,       5051,       3500,       4500,       4952
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR { map[$1]="1";map1[$2]="1";next } {lin=gensub(" ","","g",$0);split(lin,map3,",");ok=1;for (i in map3) { if (map1[map3[i]]==1 || map[map3[i]]==1 ) { ok=0 } } if (ok==1) { print $0 } }' file1 file2
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {                                   # Process the first file
               map[$1]="";                       # Set up two arrays, one for 
                                                   the first space delimited 
                                                   field and the other for 
                                                   the second
               map1[$2]="";
               next                              # Skip to the next record
              } 
              {
               lin=gensub(" ","","g",$0);        # Process the second file and remove 
                                                   all spaces from the the line 
                                                   putting the result in a variable 
                                                   lin
               split(lin,map3,",");              # Split the variable lin into the 
                                                   array map3 based on commas as the 
                                                   separator
               ok=1;                             # Initialise a variable
               for (i in map3) { 
                 if (map1[map3[i]] || map[map3[i]]) { 
                    ok=0                         # Loop through each entry in the map3 
                                                   array (on the line) and check if it 
                                                   exists in map1 or map. If it does 
                                                   exist, set ok to 0
                 } 
               } 
               if (ok==1) { 
                 print $0                         # Only if the variable ok is 1, 
                                                    print
               } 
              }' file1 file2
```

Comment: You should mention that requires an awk that supports the non-POSIX function `gensub()`, e.g. GNU awk.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
    a[$1] = $2                                  # save $1 as key, and $2 as value
    next                                        # skip the following codes for file1
}
{
    len = split(gensub("^ +", "", 1), ary, " *, *")
                                                # remove leading spaces and split on commas,
                                                # then assign ary to the field values of file2
    matched = 0                                 # reset the flag
    for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {                # loop over the fields of file2
        if (ary[i] in a) {                      # if $1 in file1 is found
            for (j = 1; j <= len; j++) {        # then go into a deeper loop to search $2 in file1
                if (a[ary[i]] == ary[j]) {      # if $2 is also found in the same record
                    matched = 1                 # then set the flag
                    break                       # and exit from the inner loop
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!matched) print                         # print the line unless "matched"
}' file1 file2
```

The result for the provided example is *all records except the line*:

```
     4651,       4651,       4652,       4752,       4751
```

Comment: You should mention that requires an awk that supports the non-POSIX function `gensub()`, e.g. GNU awk.